# javascript project to teach kids english alphabet

Tags: javascript, html

ask us to write a
In this project, you are required to implement a simple web application that allows kids in
schools to learn the basic English Alphabet. The basic idea is that, the user will choose
the number of letters he wants to learn, and when clicking on each letter, another page is
opened showing an image of something that begins with that letter. In addition, some user
interaction events are collected and stored in the localStorage object of the browser to be
used in subsequent versions of the project.
The application should look something like the following:
• It has an index.html page contains a number input and a button. The user chose
how many letters (from 1 up to 26) he wants to learn, then he presses OK.
A randomly chosen letters should be selected. For example, if the user wants to
learn 3 letters, he uses the number input field and chose 3, then presses OK and
after that he will get 3 randomly chosen letters from the English alphabet.
• The next step is for the user to click on one of the letters and then an Image is
displayed showing something that begins with that letter. Images are stored in a
folder for created for each letter (You should download some images from the
internet to use them in the project).

and i am stuck at this point that when i click in the bottun generate it generate the litters but it also diplay the images !! and i cant solve it
this is the code

```
var div2 =document.getElementById("div2"); 
var div3 =document.getElementById("div3");
var generate = document.getElementById("generate");
var input = document.getElementById("input"); 
var letters = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'];
litterImg = [];
for (let i = 0;i < 26;i++) {
    litterImg[i] = 'img\\Letter.jpg';
    
}
console.log(litterImg[0]);
//console.log(numberOfLitters);
var randomLetter = [];
var getRandomLetter = [] ;
var getRandomLetter1 ;
var linkImg = [];
var numberOfLitters
var randomNumber=[];
var x ;
generate.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    numberOfLitters = input.valueAsNumber;
    for (let index = 0; index < numberOfLitters; index++) {
        randomNumber[index] = Math.floor(Math.random()*26);
    }
    for (let index = 0; index < numberOfLitters; index++) {  
        x++ ;
        randomLetter[index]  = document.createElement("input");
        randomLetter[index].setAttribute("type","button");
        randomLetter[index].setAttribute("value",letters[randomNumber[index]]);
        randomLetter[index].setAttribute("id",randomNumber[index]);
        randomLetter[index].setAttribute("class","Letter");
        div2.appendChild(randomLetter[index]);
        
}
for (let index = 0; index < numberOfLitters; index++) {
    randomLetter[index].onclick = addImg();
    function addImg(){
    linkImg[index] = document.createElement("img");
    linkImg[index].setAttribute("src",litterImg[randomNumber[index]]);
    div3.appendChild(linkImg[index]);}
}
});
```

and this is the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta>
        <title>Alphabet Learner</title>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color: salmon;">
        <div id="div" class="div">
            <h1>Learn the English Litters </h1>
            <label >Number of Litters: </label>
            <input type="number" class="input" id="input" >
            <input type="button" class="generate" id="generate" value="Generate">
            <div id="div2" class="div2" style="margin-left: 123px;
            margin-top: 20px;">
            </div>
            <div id="div3" class="div3"></div>
        </div>
        <script src="code.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the input elements you created with document.querySelectorAll('.div2 input') and then loop with that to know what is the id or the value of the input clicked.

```
...    
// create allInputs variable
var allInputs;

generate.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  
  numberOfLitters = input.valueAsNumber
  for (let index = 0; index < numberOfLitters; index++) {
    randomNumber[index] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 26)
  }
  
  for (let index = 0; index < numberOfLitters; index++) {
    x++
    randomLetter[index] = document.createElement('input')
    randomLetter[index].setAttribute('type', 'button')
    randomLetter[index].setAttribute('value', letters[randomNumber[index]])
    randomLetter[index].setAttribute('id', randomNumber[index])
    randomLetter[index].setAttribute('class', 'Letter')
    div2.appendChild(randomLetter[index])
  }

  /* Here you select all the input you created */

  allInputs  = document.querySelectorAll('.div2 input');
  console.log(allInputs);
  for (let index = 0; index < allInputs.length; index++) {
    allInputs[index].addEventListener('click', function(e) {

        /* Here you can use the allInputs[index] to get the id or the value of your input and create your image with that index or value, check your console */

    console.log(allInputs[index])
    console.log(allInputs[index].value)
    console.log(allInputs[index].id)
       
    });
  }
})
```